# Angular app on minikube: blank page with no error

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, minikube

I have an Angular app, i build the image:

```
# stage 1
FROM node:10-alpine as node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app/
RUN npm run build

# stage 2
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=node /app/dist/apps-frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I run and access to container successfully, i also create a deployment and service,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ang-frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: ang-frontend
  ports:
    - port: 4200
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
  - 172.17.61.90
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ang-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ang-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ang-frontend
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: ang-frontend
        image: register_user_name/repo_name:tag
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

The port is well exposed, i can reach the pod via cmd: curl http://172.17.118.30:30242/
But when i try to reach it via the browser (chrome or opera), i get a blank page, and browser try to reach the pods continually
[image]

The pod logs give me this:

```
172.18.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:16:58:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:16:58:37 +0000] "GET /runtime.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://172.17.118.30:30242/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:16:58:37 +0000] "GET /polyfills.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://172.17.118.30:30242/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:16:58:37 +0000] "GET /styles.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://172.17.118.30:30242/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:16:58:37 +0000] "GET /scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://172.17.118.30:30242/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:16:58:37 +0000] "GET /vendor.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://172.17.118.30:30242/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:16:58:37 +0000] "GET /main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://172.17.118.30:30242/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125" "-"
```

Everything was okay two days ago.
I tried to clean cache but in vain
Any idea about the problem or how to debug it ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try run `minikube tunnel`

Services of type `LoadBalancer` can be exposed via the `minikube tunnel` command. It must be run in a separate terminal window to keep the `LoadBalancer` running. Ctrl-C in the terminal can be used to terminate the process at which time the network routes will be cleaned up. See more: [minikube-tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel).

Also take a look: [minikube-proxy](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/530).